How to remove tiny outlines on corners?
I am working on an input field with a gradient border on hover and focus. I came up with this snippet that technically works:
<div class="rounded-lg bg-gradient-to-tr from-yellow-600 via-red-600 to-purple-600">
  <input class="rounded-lg border border-gray-300 bg-clip-padding px-4 py-2 transition duration-200 hover:border-transparent focus:border-transparent focus:outline-none" />
</div>

https://play.tailwindcss.com/g4r07nPkLe
However, it produces tiny halo-like double borders on every corner. Please take a look at the attached image:

Through trial and error, I discovered that the background gradient image causes it. If it is removed, the tiny halos go away. It is not there when hovered or focused, either. Is there any way to fix it?

This is interesting. If I zoom-in my browser to 500%, this almost disappears, but if I zoom out to 50% it becomes more noticeable, which is the opposite of what I would have expected. And the behavior is the exact same on both Firefox and Chrome (tested both on macOS).

It is necessary to use an additional element, or a pseudo-element. For example:
<div class="flex h-full flex-col items-center justify-center">
    <div class="relative group rounded-lg">
        <input class="rounded-lg border border-gray-300 bg-clip-padding px-4 py-2 transition duration-200 hover:border-transparent focus:border-transparent focus:outline-none relative z-10" />
        <div class="absolute inset-0 rounded-lg bg-gradient-to-tr from-yellow-600 via-red-600 to-purple-600 opacity-0 transition-opacity duration-200 group-hover:opacity-100 group-focus-within:opacity-100"></div>
    </div>
</div>


I wonder why it is happening. Is it a Tailwind issue or just a general CSS bug?

Tailwind is just a tool.

I experimented with it more, and the div inside the div behaves the same way. This is how CSS works.

You use like this→
<div class= "rounded-lg bg-gradient- 
to-tr from-yellow-600 via-red-600 
to-purple-600 p-2">
<input class= "rounded-lg border 
 border-gray-300 bg-clip-padding
 px-4 py-2 transition duration-200 
 hover:border-transparent 
 focus:border-transparent 
 focus:outline-none focus:ring-0"/>
  </div>


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
